# Bundle NodeJS http2 application with webpack, http2 not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, http2

Regarding to the webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries) for external libraries and nodejs, there is the information that one should be able to import node modules. This works perfectly unless I want to import **http2**. It prints the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'absolutepath/to/src'
```

The entry typescript file simplified looks like this:

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { createSecureServer } from 'http2';

const server = createSecureServer({...});
```

And the webpack configuration file looks like follows:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  node: {
    global: true,
    process: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    http2: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'), 'node_modules/'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json']
  },
  mode: 'production'
}
```

And the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ]
  }
}
```

E.g. importing **fs** works without errors. I also have seen the [node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser#readme) plugin where the http2 module is not listed. But I don't want to use http2 within the browser but just for bundling my backend application. Any suggestions or ideas?
Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the reason for bundling a server-side app via webpack?

Comment: I thought about smaller application size for electron or cordova applications in combination with uglify. But you are right, it is not that important as bundling for client side.

Comment: I see. I guess you could still use tools like uglify, without webpack, to minify the individual JavaScript files coming out of the TypeScript transpiler?